# Can you cout an entered newline character (C++)?

Tags: c++, newline

Say I would like to be able to cout something with formatting (i.e. newlines, tabs)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string str;
int main() 
{
getline(cin, str);
cout << str;
}
```

So I would enter something like `Hey\nThere` to get a newline in between hey and there. However, it spits out exactly what I typed (`Hey\nThere`). Is it possible to cout it as I would have liked it to (see below)?

```
Hey
There
```

Comment: On which OS? `\n` is usually an end-of-line marker!

Comment: It seems like you want to **unescape** an escaped string. You will need to do that manually. String manipulation is not magic. In **string literals,** you have special syntax for escape characters, but **user-enterd input is not a string literal.** It's not part of the language, hence it's not unescaped automatically (that would be horrible). Thus, you will need to find the `\n` in your string yourself and replace it with a newline character.

Comment: And note that you´re searching for two chars: '\\' and 'n'. These two should be repalced by one '\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to process the input string yourself. A simple implementation would be like follows:

```
std::string UnescapeString( std::string input ){
    size_t position = input.find("\\");
    while( position != std::string::npos ){
        //Make sure there's another character after the slash
        if( position + 1 < input.size() ){
            switch(input[position + 1]){
                case 'n': input.replace( position, 2, "\n"); break;
                case 't': input.replace( position, 2, "\t"); break;
                case 'r': input.replace( position, 2, "\r"); break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
        position = input.find("\\", position + 1);
    }
    return input;
}
```

You can of course add more complex parsing rules for things like char escape sequences, Unicode escape sequences, and other potentially desirable escape sequences.

Comment: Can I ask, why is it so that I must search for '//' and not just '/'?

Comment: You must search for "\\" because a forward slash in your code denotes the beginning of an escape sequence. This is to disambiguate the user's intentions. If someone wrote "\", how would the compiler be able to determine that the author meant a single forward slash in a string rather than a string starting with a double quote? "\\" is just the escape sequence that means "emit one forward slash." It's essentially the same thing as "\n", but it makes a slash instead of newline.